# Predicate is not stacking in foreach loop

Tags: predicate

In the following code, `predicate` is not stacking in `foreach` loop and the results are not returned.

```
foreach (var item in rProfilesids)
{
    if (typeid=="3")
    {
        predicate = predicate.And(z => pTypes.Contains(z.PTypeId.ToString()));
    }
}
int lst = query.Where(predicate).Select(x => x.PartId).Distinct().ToList().Count();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the result currently returned? any errors? or returns 0. Unless you post your input data structure and what is the expected output, it is difficult for anyone to post an answer to your question.

Comment: @Thangadurai it returns 0

Comment: var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True(query);
var rProfilesids = GetReportProfileslists(selectedReportProfile).Where(y => cpaselections.Contains(y.Text)).Select(a => new { a.Value, a.Type }).ToList();